# Enlarge Bounding Rect of Tesseract OCR

Tags: opencv, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract OCR along with OpenCV to get the numbers from a Mat image, zeros in particularly, but it happens quite often that Tesseract doesn't recognize the zero in the right way. I think this happen because the bounding rect it's too small and cuts portion of the digit so a '0' became a 'c' or a 'n'.
There's a way to enlarge the bounding rect? Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
  Mat img1 = imread("Input/05.png");
  cvtColor(img1, img1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
  Size size(img1.cols*1.5,img1.rows*1.5);
  Mat img;
  resize(img1, img, size);
  //pre-processing start

  IplImage* image = new IplImage(img);
  IplImage* bWImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
  cvThreshold(image, bWImage, 180, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
  Mat patch = cvarrToMat(bWImage, true);

  //pre-processing end

  tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
  api->Init(NULL, "eng");
  api->SetImage((uchar*)patch.data, patch.cols, patch.rows, 1, patch.cols);
  //api->SetVariable("classify_bln_numeric_mode", "1");
  //api->SetRectangle(30, 400, 400, 40);
  api->Recognize(NULL);

  tesseract::ResultIterator* ri = api->GetIterator();
  tesseract::PageIteratorLevel level = tesseract::RIL_WORD;
  vector<Point> points;
  if (ri != 0){
     do {
       const char* word = ri->GetUTF8Text(level);
       float conf = ri->Confidence(level);
       int x1, y1, x2, y2;
       if(word != 0){
          ri->BoundingBox(level, &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
          rectangle(patch, Point(x1,y1), Point(x2,y2), 0, 1, 8);
          imshow("Zero", patch);
          waitKey();
          printf("word: '%s';  \tconf: %.2f; BoundingBox: %d,%d,%d,%d;\n", word, conf, x1, y1, x2, y2);
       }
       delete[] word;
     } while (ri->Next(level));
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `IplImage, cvThreshold` etc... C api is deprecated. Can you post an example image? Are you passing the bounding box to tesseract, or tesseract finds a _smaller_ box?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not correct, I pass the whole image to tesseract then it finds all the digits and bounds them with a rect that I display drawing a cv::rectangle with the coordinates of tesseract bounding rect (x1, x2,  x2, y2). I don't pass anything to tesseract. Shoud I?

Comment: It depends on your images. If you are able to segment each digit, you can pass each single box (eventually _enlarged_) to tesseract (eventually restricting the its alphabet to be just digits).